# Update a Backbone model property of type array by pushing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

Is this really the best way to add an item to an array in a Backbone Model?

```
// TODO: is there a better syntax for this?
this.set(
    'tags',
    this.get('tags').push('newTag')
)
```

Comment: I think the syntax I want is this.push('tags', 'newTag')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement model.push like this:

```
var model, Model;

Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: { tags: [] },
  push: function(arg, val) {
    var arr = _.clone(this.get(arg));
    arr.push(val);
    this.set(arg, arr);
  }
});
model = new Model;
model.on("change:tags", function(model, newTags) {
  console.log(newTags)
});
model.push("tags", "New tag1")
model.push("tags", "New tag2")
```

But maybe you should store tags in Collection, listen to its events and update models `tags` attribute.

```
var model, Model, Tags, Tag;

// Override id attribute for Tag model
Tag = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "name"
});

Tags = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Tag});

Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.tags = new Tags;
    this.tags.on("add remove reset", this.updateTags, this);
  },
  updateTags: function() {
    this.set("tags", this.tags.pluck("name"))
  }
});

model = new Model;
model.on("change:tags", function(model, newTags) {
  console.log(newTags)
});

// Reset tags
model.tags.reset([{name: "New tag1"}, {name: "New tag2"}]);

// Add tags
model.tags.add({name: "New tag3"});

// Remove tag
model.tags.remove(model.tags.get("New tag3"));
```

Comment: Extending the Backbone model in a generic way to support this might be a good option.

Comment: Personally I would prefer to use separate collection to store tags. Check my updated example to get an idea.

Comment: Yaaaaa... I've done the "collection, which holds a model, which holds a collection" thing before. I grant that it's valid--structurally sound, fits the intent of the framework, and all that. But for an array of tag strings, I think it's too much complexity. I don't need the model event features on tag objects. The goal on this one for me is syntactic concision. I do love how your model abstracts the tag updating away from the collection user though.

Comment: Sure it depends on how much functionality you need for your tags. Second approach is more complex and might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model with an attribute that is an array like this

```
TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    return {
       things:[]
    }
  }
});
```

to add an item to things on model TestModel

```
var test = new TestModel;
test.set({things:item});
```

Comment: It won't work, will override `things` array with just one item. And `defaults` syntax is incorrect.